# Xamarin: RowSelected not being called on device, fine in simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm building a simple table view based application in Xamarin. My RowSelected event on the UITableViewSource is **working perfectly in the simulator,** but isn't being called when I debug the app on my iPhone 4S running iOS 7.1

This is my code within the class which inherits UITableViewSource

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Selected");
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
    }
```

Adding a breakpoint within the method works as expected in the simulator, but the breakpoint never gets hit when run on the device. No errors occur, the cell in the table just remains selected as if I hadn't overridden the RowSelected method.

I've tried loads of things including stripping out all other event code and even started the project from scratch.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you run in it on the device in debug more?

Comment: try setting cell.UserInteractionEnabled to true in your GetCell()

Comment: @choper Yes I've added other breakpoints and Console.WriteLine elsewhere and all are getting called fine.

Comment: @Chethan Thanks for the suggestion - I've already tried that. Setting cell.UserInteractionEnabled = false stops the cell from every being highlighted (both on device and simulator) and as expected stops the RowSelected event from being called in the simulator.

Comment: This sounds very strange. Can you put your sample app on dropbox somewhere so that we can try it out?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge in removing a few files from the solution I've just built it and the RowSelected is getting called correctly. I'm now adding files back until I find the cause of the problem...

Answer (score 2):

I've just bounced on this issue as well. No explanation for answer but I closed Xcode, cleaned and rebuilt the solution. In my case, the simulator was working fine but the device would not trigger the row selection.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a problem as such, have you added some Tap gesture or something to your table cell? Because that is called when you tap a row, instead of Row Selected method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't have any other gestures added.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this was to **remove a referenced DLL** from the Xamarin project which I'd compiled in Visual Studio. Instead I added the C# files that made up the DLL into the Xamarin solution and then allowed Xamarin Studio to compile them as part of the build process. This immediately fixed the problem.

One of the other things I tried was changing to the Alpha version of Xamarin Studio. At first this appeared to fix the problem but I later realised that although the main UITableView in my app was now firing the RowSelected event there was another UITableView that still wasn't working.